# Docker containers experiencing socket issue (separate Flask + Nginx containers)

Tags: nginx, docker, uwsgi, docker-compose

I am experiencing the following error with my multi-container Docker setup after running docker-compose build && docker-compose up and attempting to hit my index page:

```
[crit] 8#8: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.99.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock:", host: "192.168.99.100"
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web-app
  expose:
    - "8000"
  command: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini sample-uwsgi.ini

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  links:
    - web:web
```

nginx/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD sample-nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

nginx/sample-nginx.conf

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

web-app/Dockerfile

```
FROM ansible/ubuntu14.04-ansible:stable

WORKDIR /root
ADD application.py application.py
ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt
ADD sample-uwsgi.ini sample-uwsgi.ini

ADD ansible /srv/ansible
WORKDIR /srv/ansible

RUN ansible-playbook container-bootstrap.yml -c local
```

web-app/sample-uswgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]

module = application
callable = app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock

chown-socket = www-data:www-data

vacuum = true
enable-threads=True
die-on-term = true
```

**UPDATE**

On advice from @kryten I will be using TCP/IP

Updated nginx.conf:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass localhost:8000;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Updated uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]

module = application
callable = app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = localhost:8000

chown-socket = www-data:www-data

vacuum = true
enable-threads=True
die-on-term = true
```

and am now pursuing the following error:

```
[error] 8#8: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.99.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8000", host: "192.168.99.100"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like one of your applications is attempting to connect via a [Unix socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) instead of over TCP/IP.

This will not work from different containers, because the filesystem in one container (where the socket lives) is not accessible in the other container.

The solution is to reconfigure your application to connect over TCP/IP instead of a Unix socket.

It *might* be possible to connect by exposing the location in the filesystem where the socket resides to the other container, but I've never tried this & don't know if it would work.

Comment: I have made changes based on your suggestion and now hitting a new nginx issue posted in the update

Answer (score 6):

Since `web` and `nginx` are separate containers, nginx needs to connect to *another computer* over TCP. [Linking the containers](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#connect-with-the-linking-system) does most of the work already, you just have to point the upstream to `web:8000` instead of localhost.